# topology on continuous linear maps between metrizable locally convex spaces (i.e. Schwartz space)

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I am learning about Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. I showed that for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$, the operator $\tau_y: \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathcal{S}$ given by $\tau_yf(x) = f(x -y)$ is continuous.

For two locally convex spaces $X,Y$ with a countable family of seminorms that induce the topology, define $L(X,Y)$ to be the set of continuous linear maps from $X$ to $Y$. Is there a topology on  $L(X,Y)$ that is most common or makes the most sense? Preferably one that makes composition continuous if possible?

Comment: Given a class $\mathscr B$ of bounded subsets of $X$ (e.g., all bounded sets, compact sets, weakly compact sets, null sequences, finite sets) you have the topology of uniform convergence on all elements of $\mathscr B$ which is generated by the seminorms $T\mapsto \sup\{q(T(x)): x\in B\}$ where $B\in\mathscr B$ and $q$ is a continuous seminorm on $Y$. In these cases, composition $(S,T)\mapsto S\circ T$ typically becomes separately continuous but not jointly continuous.

Comment: @Jochen Looking over my notes on normed vector spaces, I had an idea. Let $\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{Q}$ be the families of seminorms on $X,Y$ respectively. For $p \in \mathcal{P}$ and $q \in Q$, we define $r_{p,q}: L(X,Y) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ by $r_{p,q}T = \inf\{C \geq 0: \text{for each $x \in X$, }q(Tx) \leq Cp(x)\}$. Then $r_{p,q}$ is a seminorm on $L(X,Y)$. We then give $L(X,Y)$ the topology induced by the family $\mathcal{R} = (r_{p,q})_{(p,q) \in \mathcal{P} \times \mathcal{Q}}$. Im not sure if this would be the same as what you suggested with $B$ being closed, bouned or not.

Comment: @Jochen, but I think doing this kind of thing would make composition continuous

Comment: $r_{p,q}(T)$ is finite if and only if $T:(X,p)\to (Y,q)$ is continuous which need not be the case for all $p,q$ and $T$ even for the identity $T=id$ on a Fréchet space.

Comment: @Jochen Oh wow, thanks for correcting that, I reread the theorem and for each $q \in \mathcal{Q}$, there exists $p \in \mathcal{P}$ such that $q \circ T \leq p $, but not necessarily for each $p$. That is a bit sad.

Comment: @Jochen Is the topology you mentioned above sometimes called the $\mathcal{B}$-topology (where $\mathcal{B}$ is the collection of bounded subsets)?

Comment: Maybe, although the name $\mathcal B$-convergence is not very specific. I would prefer *topology of uniform convergence on $\mathcal B$*.